# "Inertia tensor possess a type of revolution about Centre of mass" ? Can't understand this sentence

Tags: classical-mechanics, symmetry, moment-of-inertia

Goldstein pg 194, 3rd Ed.

> $$
> T_{\text {rotation }}=\frac{1}{2} I_{\alpha \beta} \omega_{\alpha} \omega_{\beta}
> $$
> where
> $$
> I_{\alpha \beta}=m_{i}\left(\delta_{\alpha \beta} r_{i}^{2}-r_{i \alpha} r_{i \beta}\right)
> $$
> is the moment of inertia tensor. To get the moment of inertia about an axis through the center of mass, choose the rotation about this axis. For a body with a continuous distribution of density $\rho(r)$, the sums in the components of the moment of inertia tensor in Eq. (5.22) reduce to
> $$
> I_{\alpha \beta}=\int_{V} \rho(\mathbf{r})\left(\delta_{\alpha \beta} r^{2}-r_{\alpha} r_{\beta}\right) d V
> $$
> As an example, let us consider a homogeneous cube of density $\rho$, mass $M$, and side $a$. Choose the origin to be at one corner and the three edges adjacent to that corner to lie on the $+x,+y$, and $+z$ axes. If we define $b=M a^{2}$, then straightforward integration of Eq. $(5.23)$ gives
> $$
> \mathbf{I}=\left(\begin{array}{rrr}
> \frac{2}{3} b & -\frac{1}{4} b & -\frac{1}{4} b \\
> -\frac{1}{4} b & \frac{2}{3} b & -\frac{1}{4} b \\
> -\frac{1}{4} b & -\frac{1}{4} b & \frac{2}{3} b
> \end{array}\right)
> $$
> Thus, **both the moment of inertia and the inertia tensor possess a type of revolution**, relative to the center of mass, very similar to that found for the linear and angular momentum and the kinetic energy in Section (1.2).

I'm not able to see how "inertia and the inertia tensor possess a type of revolution, relative to the center of mass'.

Please  help me. Thank you